# How to control the scope of runGuardsAndResolvers set to always in Angular?

Tags: angular

In our app, I've added a resolver that gets the data for a component and I added `runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always'` so that when, I navigate to the same page that I am on, the resolver will kick in and do its part. That thing works as expected.

Then I added subroutes to that routing config and now, the resolver kicks in on each navigation to deeper level, between children and from child to parent. That made me wonder what scope does that thing have. Evidence shows it spans to all children, grandchildren etc.

Is there any way to keep its scope only to its own level ?

Comment: Yes! Inject the ActivatedRouteSnapshot service and check the route. Now write your logic to handle or return nothing in an if...else. As per my knowledge, no configuration key present as of now.

Comment: Wow, so simple yet so effective. Can's see the forest for the trees agian. I'd consider that an answer, would you move your comment?

Comment: Cheers, Mike! Added it in the comments with a little more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is w.r.t. Angular v11.x (for future references)...

Yes! Inject the `ActivatedRouteSnapshot` service and check the route(s). Now you can write your logic here to handle something or return nothing in any of the conditional blocks, e.g. `if...else`. As per my knowledge, no configuration key is present as of now.